# How to know the duration of a speech in a text-to-speech C#/WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, text-to-speech

I have a text-to-speech C#/WPF application. In it I need to display the duration of each speech. I've tried using the SpeakProgress and SpeakCompleted events, but I was unsuccessful. Can someone give me a direction to go, please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If using `SpeechSynthesizer` you can use the `SpeakSsml` option and add a `<mark>` element at the end of your text. Then, listen for the Bookmark reached event, which includes the AudioPosition in milliseconds. Note that you may also need to include a very short `<break>` at the end to ensure that event gets triggered. See [this gist](https://gist.github.com/lselden/cde51ca2debdd7c7c16ea4abf621f8d5#file-out-ssml-ps1-L186) *(powershell, sorry!)* for an example.

```cs
using System;  
using System.Speech.Synthesis;  

namespace SampleSynthesis  
{  
  class Program  
  {  
    static void Main(string[] args)  
    {  

      // Initialize a new instance of the SpeechSynthesizer.  
      SpeechSynthesizer synth = new SpeechSynthesizer();  

      // Configure the audio output.   
      synth.SetOutputToDefaultAudioDevice();

      string END_MARKER = "__final__event";
      
      // replace with your own text 
      string myText = "Hello World! This is my properly XML escaped text.";

      // Build an SSML prompt in a string.  
      string str = "<speak version=\"1.0\"";  
      str += " xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis\"";  
      // change language as necessary
      str += " xml:lang=\"en-US\">"; 
      str += myText;
      // add a 50ms break because otherwise the <mark> event may not be detected, for some reason
      str += "<break time=\"50ms\">";
      // add the marker element to generate a bookmark event
      str += "<mark name=\"" + END_MARKER + "\" />";
      str += "</speak>";  

      synth.BookmarkReached += new EventHandler<BookmarkReachedEventArgs>(synth_BookmarkReached);

      // Speak the contents of the prompt synchronously.
      synth.SpeakSsml(str);  

      Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit...");  
      Console.ReadKey();  
    }  
    static void synth_BookmarkReached(object sender, BookmarkReachedEventArgs e)  
    {
      if (e.Bookmark == END_MARKER) {
        Console.WriteLine("Duration in MS is {0}", e.AudioPosition.TotalMilliseconds);
    }
  }
}
```